# Do manual transmission hybrid cars exist (or could be built)?

Tags: manual-transmission, hybrid

As I was reading this question about [manual transmission electric cars](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6179/is-it-possible-to-have-a-manual-transmission-electric-car/50264#50264), it dawn on me that the question did not really address the question of hybrid cars with manual transmissions. **Hence, are there hybrid cars with manual transmissions (or could one be built)?**

Comment: You could build one but why would you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They exist, albeit not commonly.

Honda have made 3 - the Insight, the Civic Hybrid and the CR-Z were all available with manual transmission.